# Detectar el cierre de una ventana, cuando el usuario vuelve a la web

Tags: javascript, html

En mi web los usuarios pueden pulsar un botón para hacer una acción (desde una ventana que se abre). Lo que quiero saber es cómo ejecutar una función cuando el usuario la cierra, o cuando este vuelve a la web.

Las dos formas me sirven. Esto es tan solo para comprobar el tiempo que se ha estado en esa ventana, desde que el usuario hace click en el botón (y se abre la ventana) hasta que la ventana se **cierra** o **vuelva** a la página.

- La ventana abre YouTube, no una web mía.
- No abro una pestaña, sino una pequeña ventana con un `window.open()`
- Mejor si es con JavaScript y sin jQuery *(Si no hay otra opción, no pasa nada)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo puedes hacer guardando una referencia de la ventana que has abierto y con un `setInterval` mirar si se ha cerrado o no . Aquí te dejo una función que lo puedes utilizar.

```
function openYoutube() {
    var ventana = window.open("https://youtube.com");
    var tiempo= 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
         //Comprobamos que la ventana no este cerrada
        if(ventana.closed !== false) {
          //Si la ventana ha sido cerrada, limpiamos el contador
          window.clearInterval(interval)

         alert(`Tiempo total: ${tiempo} s `)

        } else {
          //Mientras no se cierra la ventana sumamos los segundos
          tiempo +=1;
        }


    },1000)


}
```

Puedes ver como funciona [aquí](https://jsbin.com/setohaxavo/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

la misma política de origen evita que Javascript detecte tales eventos. Pero hay una solución bastante simple que le permite detectar el cierre de tales ventanas:

```
var openDialog = function(uri, name, options, closeCallback) {
    var win = window.open(uri, name, options);
    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            if (win == null || win.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                closeCallback(win);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    }, 1000);
    return win;
};
```

Lo que hace: crea una nueva ventana con los parámetros proporcionados y luego establece la función del verificador con 1s de intervalo. La función luego verifica si el objeto de la ventana está presente y tiene su propiedad cerrada establecida en falso. Si cualquiera de estos dos no es cierto, esto significa que la ventana está (probablemente) cerrada y deberíamos disparar la devolución de llamada 'closeCallback function'.

Esta función debería funcionar con todos los navegadores modernos. Hace algún tiempo, Opera causó errores al verificar las propiedades de Windows en otros dominios, por lo tanto, el bloque try..catch. Pero lo he probado ahora y parece que funciona bastante bien.

Utilizamos esta técnica para crear ventanas emergentes de inicio de sesión 'estilo Facebook' para sitios que no las admiten a través de SDK (ehem ... Twitter ... ehem). Esto requirió un poco de trabajo adicional: no pudimos recibir ningún mensaje de Twitter, pero Oauth nos redirigió a nuestro dominio, y luego pudimos colocar algunos datos en el objeto de la ventana emergente a los que se podía acceder desde el abridor. Luego, en la función de devolución de llamada cerrada, analizamos esos datos y presentamos los resultados reales.

Un inconveniente de este método es que la devolución de llamada se invoca DESPUÉS de que la ventana se haya cerrado. Bueno, esto es lo mejor que pude lograr con las políticas de dominios cruzados implementadas.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17744260/10158153

Hice un pequeño ejemplo con el código anterior así:

```js
const seCerro = () => {
      alert();
    }

    var openDialog = function(uri, name, options) {
        var win = window.open(uri, name, options);
        var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            try {
                if (win == null || win.closed) {
                    window.clearInterval(interval);
                    seCerro();
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }, 1000);
        return win;
    };
 openDialog("https://www.youtube.com","Youtube","width=500,height=300");
```

Puedes verlo funcionar [aquí](https://jsbin.com/sabujewode/edit?html,js,output)